# print lines if $2<25 from text files with sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to `print $1 and $2 if $2<25`from text files. I also need to get the total number of students with marks less than 25 from all files. How can I do this with awk or sed?

```
students  marks
jerry     12
peter     35
john      5
jerry     15
john      10
```

Desired output

```
jerry    12
john      5 
jerry     15
john      10

Total no:of students :- 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk '$2<25 {print; i++} END{print "\nTotal number of students:- "i}' file
```

Output:

```
jerry     12
john      5
jerry     15
john      10

Total number of students:- 4
```

If you want the output sorted by grade *(lowest to highest)*:

```
$ sort -n -k2,2 file | awk '$2<25 {print; i++} END{print "\nTotal number of students:- "i}'
```

Sorted Output:

```
john      5
john      10
jerry     12
jerry     15

Total number of students:- 4
```

`-n` numerical sort;
`-k2,2` sort on the second field.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$2<25{count++ ; print}END{print "Total No of Students :-",count}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> awk '$2<25{count++ ; print}END{print "Total No of Students :-",count}' temp
jerry     12
john      5
jerry     15
john      10
Total No of Students :- 4
```